# Calculation: all alphanumeric passcode combinations

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

This is a statement from the Apple Platform Security document:

> The iteration count is calibrated so that one attempt takes approximately 80 milliseconds. This means it would take more than five and one-half years to try all combinations of a six-character alphanumeric passcode with lowercase letters and numbers.

**Question**: What calculation was used to determine that the duration is five and one-half years?

What would the time duration be for a seven, eight, nine and ten-character alphanumeric password with lowercase letters and numbers?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: I added a "combinatorics" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alphanumeric = $26$ lowercase letters and $10$ numbers, so there are $36$ choices for each character.

Since there are $6$ characters, and each character has the same number of choices, there are in total $36^6 = 36 \times 36 \times 36 \times 36 \times 36 \times 36$ possibilities, which is roughly $2.177 \cdot 10^9$.

So this would take $(2.177 \cdot 10^9) \cdot (80 \cdot 10^{-3})$ seconds. Converting this into years (seconds, minutes, hours, days, years), we have:

$$(2.177 \cdot 10^9) \cdot (80 \cdot 10^{-3}) \cdot \frac{1}{60} \cdot \frac{1}{60} \cdot \frac{1}{24} \cdot \frac{1}{365} \approx 5.52 \text{ years}$$

For any other number of characters, say $n$, repeat this process but with $36^n$ instead of $36^6$.

If you increase the number of characters by $1$, you add an extra factor of $36$ into the calculation without changing anything else, so the decoding time increases exponentially.

Comment: The principles are good, but your 3rd significant digit is wrong.  To see this, try opening the web developer tools of your browser and type the JavaScript code `Math.pow(36,6)*(8e-2)/(365*86400)` in the console, and you'd get the approximation `5.522025205479452`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have now edited.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that it would take ~198 years' to brute force a 7 alphanumeric passcode? Question: how long would this be if the 80ms delay was not imposed?

Comment: thanks for the great post @toby

Comment: @XXXX No problem! Your value for the alphanumeric passcode is correct, and actually rounds up to 199 years. If the 80ms delay was not imposed, then the speed would be limited by the server. I expect that the time would decrease by at least a factor of $10$.

Comment: @TobyMak would you be able to translate this to computing power? What clock speed would the server be running at to decrease the time by a factor of 10?

Comment: I don't have the experience, so I can't answer that question. You might be able to ask at Information Security SE.

Answer (score 1):

There are 36 possible characters if you use lowercase and numbers 0-9, this means in every digit you input there are 36 times more new different combinations, this means you can describe the number of possible combinations with $36^n$ where n denotes the number of digits the password has. If you want to work out how long it would take to brute force this password using the 80ms you have given you would simply have to times the 80 by the number of combinations.